# Can't login using Appcelerator Studio nor the CLI

Tags: appcelerator

I have all the necessary prerequisites (Node.js,etc) but when I try to log into Appcelerator Studio I get a repeating  dialog box asking for my credentials. I'm positive I'm typing in the right info because I can log into the main website. After a timeout period I get the error ECONNRESET. I've tried to different solutions given in the documentation. Anyone have any other suggestions?

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.core 4 0 2016-01-29 11:47:02.463
!MESSAGE (Build 4.4.0.1445622407) [ERROR]  null
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:381)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:345)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processResult(ProcessRunner.java:432)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeAppcCLI.runCommand(NodeAppcCLI.java:239)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.verifyAppcWhoami(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1181)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.access$4(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1178)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$3.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:301)

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp 4 0 2016-01-29 11:47:02.481
!MESSAGE (Build 4.4.0.1445622407) [ERROR]  Failed to check login status. Likely not logged in.

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp 4 0 2016-01-29 11:49:28.471
!MESSAGE (Build 4.4.0.1445622407) [ERROR]  login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

login failed, please try again

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

2016-01-29T16:49:28.366Z | ERROR  | read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: did you sign up using github? In that case, set up a password for your appcelerator account

Comment: No i didn't. I have a password for my acct.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to try:

- Ensure you have the latest [Studio](https://web.appcelerator.com/product/studio) version.
- Ensure you have the latest `appcelerator` CLI

  ```
  $ npm install -g appcelerator
  ```
- Review your workspace log file (`appc-log.txt`), which may contain the login errors.
- If you're on a Mac and are running El Capitan, you may need to install the [legacy Java 6 runtime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
- Try logging in from the command line, then logging out using the deauthorize switch:

  ```
  $ appc login
  $ appc logout --deauthorize
  ```
- Try resetting Studio configuration by deleting `~/.appcelerator` folder and running again.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post with the log if you have any other suggestions

Comment: I have the same issue! @RaquelJones any luck with this yet?